# MPI topology for arbitrary domains

Tags: mpi, topology, cartesian

I have a rectangular domain 3 x 2 as shown in figure (a). Using MPI Cartesian topology, I can identify the 4 neighbors (-1 means NULL) of each cell as demonstrated below

[Figure: Rectangular and arbitrary domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf27Q.jpg)

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank, size;
    int top = 0, right = 1, bottom = 2, left = 3;
    int neighbors[4], dimSize[2] = {3, 2};
    int usePeriods[2] = {0, 0}, newCoords[2];
    MPI_Comm cartComm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (size != 6) {
        if (rank == 0)
            printf("Please Launch with ONLY 6 processes  \n");
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(0);
    }

    // Create a carthesian communicator
    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dimSize, usePeriods, 1, &cartComm);

    // Obtain the 2D coordinates in the new communicator
    MPI_Cart_coords(cartComm, rank, 2, newCoords);

    // Obtain the direct neighbor ranks
    MPI_Cart_shift(cartComm, 0, 1, neighbors + left, neighbors + right);
    MPI_Cart_shift(cartComm, 1, 1, neighbors + top, neighbors + bottom);

    printf("Rank: %d \t Neighbors(top, right, bottom, left): %2d, %2d, %2d, %2d \n", rank, neighbors[0], neighbors[1], neighbors[2], neighbors[3]);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Rank: 0      Neighbors(top, right, bottom, left): -1,  2,  1, -1
Rank: 1      Neighbors(top, right, bottom, left):  0,  3, -1, -1
Rank: 2      Neighbors(top, right, bottom, left): -1,  4,  3,  0
Rank: 3      Neighbors(top, right, bottom, left):  2,  5, -1,  1
Rank: 4      Neighbors(top, right, bottom, left): -1, -1,  5,  2
Rank: 5      Neighbors(top, right, bottom, left):  4, -1, -1,  3
```

My question: Is there a way that uses MPI to identify these neighbors for non-rectangular domain as shown in figure (b). Here, we assume no periodic neighbors. Now, I can only think of implementing a similar Cartesian topology approach for 3x3 (figure c):

```
mpirun -np 9 ./run_cartesian
```

Next, remove NULL cells (gray color) and reorder the ranks from 0-5. Save result to a file, then load the file (using root) and scatter the corresponding neighbors to each processor.

```
mpirun -np 6 ./run_load_scatter
```

Any suggestion for better ways to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You could store the connectivity in a (distributed) graph topology but it does not provide a notion of "up", "left", etc. and hence no functionality similar to `MPI_Cart_shift`.

Comment: I see your point @HristoIliev. Graph topology is nice and provides a chance to solve the problem in this case. Given the order of the grid, we can identify the 4 neighbors of each cells based on the magnitudes (small to large: left, top, bottom, right). Now, the problem is that at the edge (less than 4 neighbors) we won't have enough information to identify them using this rule.

Comment: If you hack the topology and use different weights for each direction, you could obtain the list of neighbours and their weights and thus determine the direction towards each neighbour.